$\sum a_n X_n$ where $X_n$ is gaussian $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$
This is a problem that I've been recently wondering about. It may be trivial, but for some reason it doesn't feel so to me. Suppose I have a sequence of gaussians, and I'm trying to multiply it with non-zero scalars and add them. That is,

Consider $X:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n X_n$ where $X_n$ is drawn IID from $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$. Assuming that $a_n \neq 0$ for all $n$, under what condition on $\{a_n\}$ is $\mathbb{E}[X]=0$?

If $X$ is a finite series, then of course the expectation is zero due to linearity. But I am unsure what happens for infinite series. Furthermore, is there a way to quantify the rate/variance of convergence? Intuitively, if $a_n =1/n$, then the variance of $X$ is $\sum_n \sigma^2/n^2$, as opposed to  $a_n =1$ where variance is infinite.

Well, to talk at all about $X$, we need to assume that $X$ is an almost surely finite random variable.
In that case, you have that almost surely $S_{n}:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$ converges to $X$.  Thus you also have convergence in distribution.
Now suppose that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}^{2}\uparrow\infty$. Then, the problem is that
for any fixed $M>0$, there exists $N$ such that $\frac{M}{\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}^{2}}}<0.1$ for $n\geq N$.
$$P(|S_{n}|>M)=P(\frac{|S_{n}|}{\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}^{2}}}>\frac{M}{\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}^{2}}})\geq 0.9$$ as $\frac{|S_{n}|}{\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}^{2}}}$ has Standard Normal Distribution,
Thus for all $n\geq N$, you have that $P(|S_{n}|>M)\geq 0.9$ . This violates the condition of Tightness of the sequence which is necessary for convergence in distribution.
Thus, we have shown that if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}^{2}=\infty$, then the sequence $S_{n}$ cannot converge almost surely.
So, it suffices to stick to the case of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}^{2}<\infty$.
In this case, note that $E(S_{n}^{2})=\sigma^{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}^{2}$ and hence $\sup_{n}E(S_{n}^{2})<\infty$.
This means that $S_{n}$ is uniformly integrable. And hence $E(X)=\lim_{n\to\infty}E(S_{n})=0$

Alternatively One can note that the characteristic function for $S_{n}$ is given by $\psi_{n}(t)=\exp(it-t^{2}\sigma^{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}^{2}/2)$.
Thus, if $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}^{2}\to\infty$, then $\psi_{n}(t)\to 0$ which is not a characteristic function. And, if $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}^{2}\to a^{2}$, then $\psi_{n}(t)\to\exp(it-\sigma^{2}a^{2}t^{2}/2)$ which is the characteristic function of a $N(0,a^{2}\sigma^{2})$ variate. And thus $E(X)=E(N(0,a^{2}\sigma^{2}))=0$.

Very nice and detailed solution. Especially the one with the characteristic function is very elegant.

In particular $S_n := \sum_{i=1}^n a_nX_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^na_n^2)$. So if $\sum_{i=1}^n a_n^2$ converges to, say, some $a^2 \in (0, \infty)$, the limiting distribution of $S_n$ is $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2a^2)$, so the mean is $0$. If $\sum_{i=1}^n a_n^2$ does not converge, no limiting distribution exists, and therefore asking what its expectation is, is not a well-defined question.

Nice answer(+1). I have provided the necessary justifications and elaborations in mine.
